# Where to find console.log's output written in Javascript of mobile support in Moodle Plugin?

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

While developing Mobile Support for Moodle Plugins, we can use Javascript that is defined in plugin/classes/output/mobile.php.

Where can I find the console.log's output written in this Javascript file?

I am developing mobile support for Flexible section course format plugin in Moodle. I have defined Javascript file in moodle/format/flexsections/classes/output/mobile.php as:

```
...
...

return [
        'templates' => [
            [
                'id' => 'main',
                'html' => $html
            ]
        ],
        'javascript' => file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../js/mobile/add_styling.js'),
        'otherdata' => [

        ]
    ];
```

And I have created a Javascript file in moodle/format/flexsections/js/add_styling.js as:

```
console.log("Debug_test");
```

Then I build a moodle app using:
`ionic cordova build android --debug`

The custom mustache template is rendered fine but when I use `adb logcat | grep "Debug_test"` there is no output by the console log.

I opened `chrome://inspect/#devices` in Google Chrome, clicked inspect and opened the console, there is no output by the console log.

Everytime I looked at the console for output, in the mobile app I go to App settings -> Space Usage -> Delete the user data and then I close and open the app, then click on the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Moodle App Plugins Development Guide](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_App_Plugins_Development_Guide#Running_JS_code_after_a_content_template_has_loaded) solved the issue.

And I found the output using:

`adb logcat | grep "Debug_test"`